# Android Annotations - Injecting a list of superclass type

Tags: java, android, spring, annotations

I am trying to achieve the following Spring code using Android Annotations:

```
@Autowired
public initHandlerList(List<Handler> handlerList) {
   // Do stuff with the list ...
}
```

I tried using both an interface and a class.

Bean definition:

```
@EBean
public AbstractHandler implements Handler {}
```

Trying to inject:

```
@Bean
public initHandlersList(List<AbstractHandler> handlersList) {
  // Do stuff with the list ...
}
```

But always got the following error:

```
Error:(20, 5) error: org.androidannotations.annotations.Bean can only be used on an element annotated with @org.androidannotations.annotations.EBean
```

So I guess since the list itself is not annotated with `@EBean` it can't be used as a Bean... any way to implement this using Android Annotations?

Thanks !

Comment: this could be helpful https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/Enhance-custom-classes

Comment: @Boldbayar Thanks but I already read their wiki, they don't show anywhere how to do something like this.. I guess It's not possible with their framework and I'll have to write some boilerplate code

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I can't comment but my reputation is too low.

I read the [wiki](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/Enhance-custom-classes) and under method based injection I saw how you inject the beans. What I can see in your code is that you are indeed creating a EBean with an AbstractHandler object however you are trying to inject a List object which has not been annotated with @EBean you can either delete the List<> and just use the AbstractHandler or you can extend a List implementation (Like ArrayList) and annotate it with @EBean.

```
@EBean
public class InjectableArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T>{}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It was a nice idea, I tried it. But what it achieves is simply injecting an empty array list. What I wanted is for the framework to actually inject a list already populated with instances of all the classes that extend AbstractHandler (like Spring can do). It seems this framework is not as powerful as Spring. Thanks anyway I appreciate it!

Comment: I see, yes this achives injecting a list with no elements. As you comment I do not see any documentation that explains if this could be achived. I checked the injection documents and it looks like there is nothing of the sort. Maybe it is not supported at the time. Have a nice day.